# MVVM model binding beginner

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am new to MVVM and WPF and I am a little bit confused.

Let's say I have 2 models, like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I am not sure what is the recommended way of implementing the `ProducViewModel` class for adding a new Product:

Is it OK to just use a public property of type `Product` and bind it to the view, like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel : Screen
{
    private Product _product;
    public BindableCollection<Category> Categories;

    public ProductViewModel(Product product, BindableCollection<Category> categories)
    {
        _product = product;
        Categories = categories;
    }

    public Product Product
    {
        get { return _product }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            SetAndNotify(ref _product, value);
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I will use the `Category` collection in the form to choose a category.

My view should look something like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="Catgory" />
        <ComboBox 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
            SelectedValue="?????? What comes here? "/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Is this correct?
And also, how I will bind `Product.Category` in a `ComboBox` in the view?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try my solution below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your View Model you should expose properties that are needed in your view. This case you can bind directly to your Product.Category or create a new property in your view model, and i think this last option is well suited in a MVVM scenario.

In your case you should create a selected category property your ProductViewModel:

```
public Category SelectedCategory { get { return _selectedCategory; }
    set
    {
        _selectedCategory = value;
        SetAndNotify(ref _selectedCategory, value);
        Product.Category = _selectedCategory;
    } }
```

And then in your xaml, you bind combobox's selected value to this new property:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Content="Catgory" />
    <ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Categories}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCategory}"/>
</StackPanel>
```